# Why do the 5 lions form Voltron in deep space?

Tags: voltron, lion-force-voltron

In every season of *Voltron*, 5 lions together form Voltron. My question is: why do they always go to deep space to form Voltron? Can't they form Voltron on the planet's surface?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The possible reason may be: to have a momentary escape from the enemy and to avoid being attacked during the formation process as the lions become vulnerable during that time and it takes a lot of time to form into Voltron.

Answer (score -3):

Because the lions when they combine there uniqueness together , the space gravity enhances the coneection power , and because its freezing in  space it adds solidness of strength of the voltronic ultra robotic fierceness, if they formed together on the planets surface it will fall apart because the law of gravity would be in effect , and in space they float and the laws of gravity is ineffective in space.